# How to work with items from a list that is parallel to another list?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I tried the following code in order to get the list k to have `['c','b']` - (i.e. no `'x'`) but I get a syntax error on the penultimate line. Could someone please clarify where I have gone wrong? `j1` was introduced when `j` became a list type instead of remaining an integer. Tuple `M` would be columns of matching strings, to be imported from XL later while list `m` is user input.

```
j = 29
k = []
M = (['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a','b', 'c']) 
m = ['X','C','B']
for i in (range(len(m))):
    j = [M[0].index(m[i]) if m[i] in M[0] else 30,]
    j1 = j[0]
    k[i]= [M[1][j1] if j1 < 30 else k[j1]='']
print (k)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your Problem

`=`  is a statement. You cannot use it inside a list comprehension, which is an expression. There this line does not work:

```
k[i]= [M[1][j1] if j1 < 30 else k[j1]='']
```

### Better Solution

Use a dictionary and a list comprehension:

```
>>> M = (['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a','b', 'c']) 
... m = ['X','C','B']
... mapping = dict(zip(*M))
... k = [mapping[x] for x in m if x in mapping]
... k
...
['c', 'b']
```

Comment: Thanks - your solution works for now! I request one clarification - if M has 5 columns and I want to work on only two of these at a time, can I zip these two columns in any order? Or does the column being searched need to be the first in the data, as it is the key in the dictionary?

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: It would be better to ask another question with  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show what you got, want your desired output is and what you did so far.